# What are some databases that are schema-full but not relational

Tags: schema, nosql

What are some databases/datastores that are schema-full, but not relational?

In other word I'm after some NoSql databases that are not schema-less.

By schema-full I mean that, like in a traditional relational sql database, **all** rows/entities/values of a given 'table' should all have the same structure, which is defined upfront and checked by the datastore.

I'm interested in object database but I'm a believer in schemas / strongly typed data...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j is a [schema-optional](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/graphdb-neo4j-schema.html) graph database.  You could choose to enforce a full schema and reap the benefits.

MongoDB v3.2 has  [validation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document-validation/) of structure and data type.